# How do you write a resolver that returns a SQLAlchemy as a relay connection?

Tags: sqlalchemy, graphene-python

I would like to return a relay connection for queries. Using standard graphene-sqlalchemy you can do this:

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    node = relay.Node.Field()

    all_users = SQLAlchemyConnectionField(User)
```

For various places where you need a more custom search the simplest approach is a custom resolver:

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    node = relay.Node.Field()


    all_users = graphene.List(User)
    def resolve_all_users(self, info, **args):
        # Grab the root SQLAlchemy query
        query = User.get_query(info)
        return query.filter(
            User.active,
            # and possibly a whole bunch of other filters)
        ).options(joinedload(User.emails).all()
```

This works, but it returns a plain list of users without any support for pagination or other relay connection tricks handled by SQLAlchemyConnectionField. What I am looking for is a way to return a query, and have it automatically handled in a similar way as SQLAlchemyConnectionField does.

Comment: I think you should rename the title of you question as follow: "How to write a resolver that return a SQLAlchemyConnectionField?".

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea.

```
def search_users(cls, info, **kwargs):
    user_query = UserQLSchema.get_query(info)
    target = kwargs.get('target')
    if target:
        target_like = "%{}%".format(target)
        user_query = orga_query.filter(UserModel.name.like(target_like))
    return user_query.all()

class RootQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
    find_users = graphene.relay.ConnectionField(OrganizationFullConnection, target=graphene.String(), resolver=search_users)
```

While, another problem will be raised, leading to query database twice for each network request.

Comment: The main problem is 
   
return user_query.all() 

will query all data

Comment: Have u any git repo @Keye Myria

Answer (score 0):

I derived another solution.

```
def search_users(cls, info, **kwargs):
    user_query = UserQLSchema.get_query(info)
    target = kwargs.get('target')
    if target:
        target_like = "%{}%".format(target)
        user_query = orga_query.filter(UserModel.name.like(target_like))
    return user_query

class RootQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
    find_users = SQLAlchemyConnectionField(UserQLSchema, target=graphene.String())

def resolve_find_users(self, info, **kwargs):
    return search_users(self, info, **kwargs)
```

May help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that add a `search_users` query with an argument `q` to filter users by email. the result is a UserConnection that has all connection features (sort, pagination, etc...)

```py
import graphene
from graphene import relay
from graphene_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyObjectType, SQLAlchemyConnectionField
from .models import User as UserModel


class User(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

class UserConnection(relay.Connection):
    class Meta:
        node = User

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    node = relay.Node.Field()

    search_users = SQLAlchemyConnectionField(UserConnection, q=graphene.String())
    def resolve_all_users(self, info, **args):
        q = args.get("q")
        users_query = User.get_query(info)
        # For now I've just copied sort implementation from UnsortedSQLAlchemyConnectionField
        # I didn't find a better way to re-use this code without duplicating it :-(
        if 'sort' in args:
            sort = args['sort']
            if isinstance(sort, str):
                users_query = users_query.order_by(sort.value)
            else:
                users_query = users_query.order_by(*(col.value for col in sort))
        users = users_query.filter(UserModel.email.contains(q)).all()
        return users
```